# Get --numstat or --stat for pretty format

Tags: git, git-log

I want to do this:

```
git log --author="<author-name>" --pretty=format:'{"stat":"%stat","numstat":"%numstat"}'
```

but in the docs:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

I don't see a way to grab numstat or stat without just using

```
--numstat / --stat
```

is there a way to get JSON output for these values?

Comment: Unfortuntely, stat and numstat outputs are not (currently?) available by any method other than the switches. In particular there are no %-directives for them.

Comment: ok thanks, if you feel like adding an answer for that please do

Answer (score 3):

Currently (Git 2.17) there are no formatting directives that obtain `--stat` or `--numstat` output.  (This is mostly an internal issue: the formatting directives do not have access to the full diff machinery, nor the results of diffs.)

Note that if file names contain "bad" characters (double quotes), the trick above would fail anyway.  It's probably better to read the `--stat` output with a separate program and do JSON-encoding on the output yourself.